# How to restructure folders using TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I have TortoiseSVN setup on my PC. I did not initially follow the regular folder structure of /trunk, /branches/ and /tags. I just created a folder and put everything in it (trunk code was in /).

Now I need to make /trunk /branch and /tags folders. How can I move all my code currently nin / to /trunk using TortoiseSVN now?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Right click on the working copy, choose TortoiseSVN->Repo-browser

Create a folder named trunk.

Drag'n drop all existing files and folders to the new trunk-folder.

Update your working copy.